what can I do "my query takin 3 sec to execute"?
@Query("from User u where u.email in :emailIds")
    List<User> findByListOfEmail(List<String> emailIds);

the above query I mentioned is taking 3 sec to complete, I don't  know how to fix.
I am not able to find the cause. Please any one know why please fix the problem.

You should check if there’s an index on your email column

What database you use? Can you execute this or similar query directly in database? How long it will take?

This question - Is SQL IN bad for performance?, may give you some leads what to look for.
